# SQL Server - Dealing with a strange table relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse

The company I work for resells data so it's possible for the same "unit" to be sold twice. I'm trying to do profitability calculations but running into a headache due to how are tables are setup.

Basically we have two tables, let's call them Data and Sale.

Data:

```
dataid  cost
1       $1.00
2       $2.00
```

Sale:

```
saleid  dataid  price
1       1       $5.00
2       2       $3.00
3       2       $4.00
```

What I need to do is join the tables in such a way that the cost is only counted on its first sale. Like this:

Profit:

```
saleid  dataid  price  cost   profit
1       1       $5.00  $1.00  $4.00
2       2       $3.00  $2.00  $1.00
3       2       $4.00  $0.00  $4.00
```

I'm working nearly a billion rows so performance is a concern as well. I realize the table structure is pretty silly but refactoring the database is not an option. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean, "first"? In ascending saleid? There is no order to an SQL table. Is your illustration of an ordered SQL result set (query result)? What is the source of its ordering?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this, using [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) as suggested by Gordon Linoff from the previous answer to determine first sale.

Data:

```
    IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TmpData') IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN 
            DROP TABLE #TmpData
        END 

    CREATE TABLE #TmpData ( dataid INT, cost MONEY, )
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_TmpData_dataid ON #TmpData (dataid)

    INSERT  INTO #TmpData
            ( dataid, cost )
    VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
            ( 2, 2 )

    IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TmpSale') IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN 
            DROP TABLE #TmpSale
        END 

    CREATE TABLE #TmpSale
        (
          saleid INT ,
          dataid INT ,
          price MONEY
        )
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_TmpSale ON #TmpSale (saleid)
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TmpSale_dataid ON #TmpSale (dataid)


    INSERT  INTO #TmpSale
            ( saleid, dataid, price )
    VALUES  ( 1, 1, 5 ),
            ( 2, 2, 3 ),
            ( 3, 2, 4 )
```

using [CTE](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/) and row_number :

```
    ;WITH    PROFIT
              AS ( SELECT   d.dataid d_dataid ,
                            d.cost ,
                            s.saleid ,
                            s.dataid s_dataid ,
                            price ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY d.dataid ORDER BY s.saleid ) ctr
                   FROM     #TmpData D
                            JOIN #TmpSale S ON S.dataid = D.dataid
                 )
        SELECT  saleid ,
                d_dataid dataid ,
                price ,
                IIF(ctr = 1, cost, 0) cost ,
                IIF(ctr = 1, ( price - cost ), price) profit
        FROM    PROFIT
        OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Result:

```
    saleid      dataid      price   cost    profit
    ----------- ----------- ------- ------- --------
    1           1           5.00    1.00    4.00
    2           2           3.00    2.00    1.00
    3           2           4.00    0.00    4.00
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems really weird.  You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select s.*, coalesce(c.cost, 0) as cost,
       (s.price - coalesce(c.cost, 0)) as profit
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s.dataid order by s.saleid) as seqnum
      from sales s
     ) s left join join
     cost c
     on c.dataid = s.dataid;
```

I should note that you do want an index on `sales(dataid, saleid)` for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here note that question is not regarding index or performance.
Becasue you have  thrown sample table structure.

IMHO correct index will be,

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_TmpData_dataid ON #TmpData (dataid)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_TmpSale ON #TmpSale (saleid)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TmpSale_dataid ON #TmpSale (dataid)INCLUDE(profit)
```

Try this,

```
select saleid, dataid,t4.price,(case when rn=1 then cost else 0 end)Cost 
,price-(case when rn=1 then cost else 0 end)Profit
FROM(
select a.saleid,a.dataid,a.price, d.cost
,ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION by d.dataid order by d.dataid)rn
     from #TmpSale a
left join #TmpData d on a.dataid=d.dataid
)t4
```